# FirebaseApp.configure function is giving "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have included **pod 'Firebase/Core'** in the pod file. I have successfully installed the pod file of project.

[image: Pod installation complete!]

In workspace I included the following lines in appDelegate.swift file

```
import Firebase

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

      FirebaseApp.configure()

      return true
}
```

On running the workspace, workspace execution stops at 
**Thread 1: signal SIGABRT** error. Incase i comment this line
  **FirebaseApp.configure()** program executes and gives the output. How I can remove thread error caused due to **FirebaseApp.configure()**. From this link you can download the sample project for correction. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5pNDpbvZ8SnS04tSkRzaU8yMFk

Comment: Do you have a crash log ?

Comment: no.i dont have crash log

Comment: Have you tried FIRApp.configure()?

Comment: 'FIRApp' has been renamed to 'FirebaseApp'    Replace 'FIRApp' with 'FirebaseApp'